# How to render a raster multiple times across the date line?

Tags: mapserver

Using EPSG:4326 and WGS84, I have a GeoTIFF with longitude extents (167, 208) - so it crosses the date line. I'd like MapServer to display the image regardless of whether the user's requesting bbox comes from the west or the east, however:

```
[...]bbox=150,0,250,90[...]
```

displays the image, while

```
[...]bbox=-210,0,-110,90[...]
```

displays a blank image.

Everything else unchanged, I'd like to see the same image returned in both cases. Some research brought up this 3+ year old mail from FrankW:

http://lists.osgeo.org/pipermail/mapserver-dev/2010-February/009713.html

Points #3 & 4 imply that adding `PROCESSING "RESAMPLE=AVERAGE"` should solve this problem, but I've added that to my mapfile with no luck. Has this changed in the past few years? Is there another way I can get the desired behavior? Is there a setting I could check for that could be preventing the image from mirroring every +/- 360 degrees longitude?